# @ManyToOne relationship,JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a bidirectional many to one relationship. When I retrieve the parent object from the table, all the child objects should get retrieved but only the first one is getting retrieved
The parent looks like

```
@Entity
public class xyz{
@OneToMany(mappedBy="xyz",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<zyx> zyxDO;}
```

The child class looks like

```
public class zyx{
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private xyz xyzDO;
}
```

Is there any annotation where I can retrieve all the rows of the underlying database

Comment: Does this happen for all records or only some?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a typo, but the value of mappedBy should be the name of the attribute in the owning entity that points back to the inverse entity, in this case xyzDO.

And maybe because you are using a Set instead of a Collection could cause that only one child is retrieved (if they are identical).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by retrieve all the rows of the underlying database? You retrieve only the children which parent's key set. Note also, that fetch eager can easily cause great performance issues, because children will be fetched always, even if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set both sides of the relationships when adding/setting the relationship.